# Personal domain email using Outlook.com on Apple Mail

Tags: mail.app, email

I use Outlook.com as my email provider but have my own personal domain name instead of the one provided by Microsoft. So, instead of "**mail@outlook.com**", my email address looks like "**mail@personaldomain.com**".

I have been trying to somehow configure this email on my Apple Mail client but so far been unsuccessful. I have read several how-to's and tutorials that explain how to configure an outlook.com email on Apple Mail; however, none have explained what to do when you have a private domain running on Outlook.com. Could someone with a similar experience please help me out?

Also, though I will be more than happy to just have my email configured, it would be really great if IMAP were a possibility instead of POP3.

Comment: just to clarify the Outlook.com is actually the windows live email. and yes it comes with IMAP settings in Mail.app for OS X, TBD about your domain....

Comment: Yes, thats correct.

Comment: so what do you enter in the Outgoing and Incoming fields in mail.app

Comment: Incoming mail server: imap-mail.outlook.com. Outgoing mail server: smtp-mail.outlook.com

Comment: That should work, if you use the correct ports

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set up your Mac Mail to sync your Outlook.com account’s email:

1. Open Mac Mail.
2. From the File menu, choose Add Account…
3. Input your account information.
4. Choose Account Type: IMAP.
5. Input the following as the Incoming Mail Server: 
   imap-mail.outlook.com. (or in your case imap-mail.yourdomain.com
6. Choose to Use Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) and Port: 993 for incoming mail security.
7. Input the following as the Outgoing Mail Server: smtp-mail.outlook.com. (or replace outlook with your domain name)
8. Choose to Use Authentication.
9. Choose to Use Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) and Port: 25 for outgoing mail security.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be working. Except that now it's downloading my entire inbox! That's like thousands of read emails! Isn't there any way to tell Apple Mail to only download new/unread emails?

Comment: That is how IMAP works. If you want to download only new email, you may tray replacing the IMAP server with POP3, and the appropriate port / server information.

Comment: Update: Tried this and it still works against an Outlook.office365.com account. In fact, the addresses Buscar offered actually worked with Apple Mail (adding an IMAP account) in Mac OS 10.12.6 where the POP and IMAP settings on the webmail interface for Outlook didn't work. (smtp.office365.com failed, but Buscar's worked.) Many thanks!