# How can I config an email account in Apple Mail with my own domain?

Tags: mail.app

I am using outlook.com for my own email "mydomain.info" but I can not add an account in Apple Mail. I have searched in Ask Different for similar questions. I got this: 
[Personal domain email using Outlook.com on Apple Mail](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129781/personal-domain-email-using-outlook-com-on-apple-mail)

I have exact the same problem but the accepted answer doesn't work for me. My domain is "domain.info". I never configured an account successfully in Apple Mail from Maverick to Yosemite and now El Capitan.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't provide any more info about your email service, you must do some of the next:

- Go to your TLD admin panel, must of them already have documentation about how to configure this.
- Can you access it via web? something like *webmail.MyDomain.info*? if so, there could be some documentation in there too.
- have you already tried adding your account via

Settings > Internet Accounts > Add ( + button) > Add Other Account...

Most of the times this should work